# Sphinx wildcard searching won't work

Tags: codeigniter, sphinx, wildcard

I have used the following code:

```
   function searchSphinx2($tofind,$jobtype_id,$payper_id,$onetimeBounds)
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('sphinxclient');
        global $result;
        global $functionresult;
        $functionresult=array();

        $this->sphinxclient->setServer('localhost', 3312);
        $this->sphinxclient->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_ANY );
        $this->sphinxclient->SetIndexWeights( array("jobs_index_main"=>10, "jobs_index_delta"=>10,"jobs_index_prefix_main"=>1,"jobs_index_prefix_delta"=>1,"jobs_index_infix_main"=>1,"jobs_index_infix_delta"=>1) );

        $this->sphinxclient->ResetFilters();
        $this->sphinxclient->SetFilter('jobtype_id',$jobtype_id,TRUE);
        $this->sphinxclient->SetFilter('payper_id',$payper_id,TRUE);
        $this->sphinxclient->SetFilterFloatRange('payamount', $ontimeBounds[0], $ontimeBounds[1], FALSE);

        $this->sphinxclient->AddQuery("$tofind", "jobs_index_main;jobs_index_delta");
        $this->sphinxclient->AddQuery("*$tofind*", "jobs_index_main_prefix;jobs_index_delta_prefix");
        $this->sphinxclient->AddQuery("*$tofind*", "jobs_index_main_infix;jobs_index_delta_infix");
        $result = $this->sphinxclient->RunQueries();
```

In my data base there is a job with title "Intern"  However, if I search for "inter" I do not get any results.

The indices in my confi file are set up as follows:

```
index jobs_index_prefix_main
{
        source  = jobs_main
        path = /var/newsphinx/index/main_prefix

        morphology = stem_en
        min_stemming_len = 4
        min_word_len = 3
        min_prefix_len = 3
        prefix_fields = title, contactname
        enable_star =1
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not getting partial word results?

Answer (score 0):

I've never found Sphinx to return partial matches without using stars. I agree that it's not particularly intuitive (surely if the prefixes are being indexed, there's a match?), but if you want to ensure you always get results, add a star to the end of each word.